# Spring data mongodb concurrent get and update is thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, mongodb, concurrency

I have the following problem: I have a java service that sums or subtract a value stored on my mongodb database.

For example, if I have the value 100 on the database, and my service is called with the value 10, then the following occurs:

- I get the value 100 from the database
- I sum 100 with the value 10
- I save the new value (110) on the database again

However, I'm afraid of concurrency. What happens if a lot of people call the same service? I'm afraid of inconsistent value in the end of the process.

**The question is**: This process described above is thread safe ? (I believe it is not). What should I do to keep my data consistent and deal with this thread concurrency?

**UPDATE**

Below follows the code

```
public void update(Size entity, Integer newValue) {
    Size size = repository.findOneById(entity.getId());
    size.setTotal(size.getTotal() + newValue);
    repository.update(size);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **it is not thread-safe** as it is not done atomically since `MongoDB` is **not a transactional database**, you are supposed to use  `$inc` operator for such need as it allows to increment **atomically** given fields of given amounts, more details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).